# complete dynamic array observables one by one (concatMap)

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable, concatmap

I am making a chat app and I would like to save messages in the correct order.

Imagine, I would have a static number of messages

```
// 4 messages. array of static length: 4
chatMessages: string[] = ['hello', 'world', 'and', 'stack overflow members']; //
```

now, let's create a save observables for them.

```
chatMessages: Observable<ChatMessage>[] = chatMessages.map((message: string) => {
    return chatService.saveMessage(message); // returns an Observable to call API
})
```

Now, I want to save them one by one, one after another.

I do it this way:

```
from(chatMessages).pipe(
    concatMap((observable) => observable),
     toArray(),
     take(1)
).subscribe();
```

Now My question is, if the initial chatMessages array is dynamic - (can be added a message in any point of time, even during saving).
How do I loop the array to save chat messages one by one, keeping the order they were added ?

For example: two out of four messages were saved, the 3rd is being processed, and in that moment the 5th message is added to the chatMessages array. How do I manage that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the initial chatMessages array is dynamic - (can be added a message in any point of time, even during saving)

You are describing an Observable of Message (string), not an array!  Since you are processing items one at a time, there is no need for array.

You can just use a simple subject that emits messages as they are received and have one subscription to that stream that saves the messages for you:

```js
chatMessage$ = new Subject<string>();

function saveMessage(message: string) {
    chatMessage$.next(message);
}

chatMessage$.pipe(
    concatMap(message => chatService.saveMessage(message))
).subscribe();
```

This will processes the new messages one at a time, in the correct order.

Comment: Just wanted to post that I found the answer. And see you already answered. Thanks. I did exactly like you told.

Comment: one more thing that I am just interested in: If there will be an API endpoint that will support multiple message saving, so if there 3 items in the queue - then save 3, if 1 - then 1... The queue is filled during the API request. For example, during saving 3 messages, 2 more were added and now need to save those two. The queue is filled one by one. But it should be saved entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right the problem, you have to deal with with an array which can receive additional element over time and such elements have to be added at the end of the array.

This can be seen as a stream of messages, the ones originally stored in the array being the first elements of the stream, to which it is possible to add other messages over time, for instance calling a specific function `addMessage(msg)`.

The code to build such stream could look like this

```
const myInitialArray = ['hello', 'world', 'and', 'stack overflow members']
function saveMessage(msg: string) {
  return of(`saved: ${msg}`).pipe(delay(1000))
}

const add$ = new Subject<string>()

const myStream = merge(from(myInitialArray), add$).pipe(
  concatMap(msg => saveMessage(msg))
)
```

Now what you have to do is to `subscribe` to `myStream` and, any time you want to add a message at the end of the array (or stream), you have to call the function `addMessage`.

[This stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-setx2a?file=index.ts) shows the example working.

Comment: Thanks, the `Subject()` is the answer.

Comment: one more thing that I am just interested in: If there will be an API endpoint that will support multiple message saving, so if there 3 items in the queue - then save 3, if 1 - then 1... The queue is filled during the API request. For example, during saving 3 messages, 2 more were added and now need to save those two. The queue is filled one by one. But it should be saved entirely.

Comment: It looks similar to this question+(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70851715/rxjs-how-to-get-all-values-that-are-buffered-during-a-concatmap). It seems you are looking for something that does combine buffering with `concatMap`.